# General solution to homogeneous ODE with variable coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$(1+t^2)x''-2x=0$$
I'm trying to find the general solution. I already know the solution (Wolfram), but I want to know how to solve it.

First because of the coefficient $1+t^2$,  suppose the solution $x(t)=at^2+bt+c$. Plugging in
$$(1+t^2)(2a)-2(at^2+bt+c)=0$$
$$2a+2at^2-2at^2-2c=0 \Rightarrow a=c,~b=0$$
so the particular solution is of the form $$x_p(t)=at^2+a$$
Now I need the complementary solution, but I don't know how to get it.
Also this is NOT homework

Comment: try plugging a power series of the form $x = \sum_{n{\geq 0}} a_nt^n$ into that equation and see if you can find an explicit formula for the $a_n$'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you found $y_1(t)=1+t^2$ as one solution. Then the order reduction process of Frobenius tells you to find a second basis solution as $y_2(t)=u(t)y_1(t)$.
This leads to the equation
$$
(1+t^2)(u''y_1+2u'y_1')=0.
$$
One non-trivial solution of that satisfies
$$
u'(t)=\frac{1}{y_1(t)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}
$$

Comment: Trying to get to where you got + checking the reduction method! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

write $$-2=-\frac{d^2(t^2+1)}{dt^2}$$
then we can write
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\frac{d(t^2+1)}{dt^2}+\frac{d^2x(t)(t^2+1)}{dt^2}-\frac{d^2x(t)(t^2+1)}{dt^2}-\frac{d^2(t^2+1)(t^2+1)x(t)}{dt^2}=0$$
integrating
$$\frac{dx(t)(t^2+1)}{dt}-2tx(t)=C_1$$
with
$$\mu(t)=e^{\int\frac{-2t}{t^2+1}dt}=\frac{1}{t^2+1}$$ 
we have
$$\frac{\frac{dx(t)}{dt}}{t^2+1}-\frac{2tx(t)}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{C_1}{(t^2+1)^2}$$
then we get
$$\frac{x(t)}{t^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\arctan(t)\right)C_1+C_2$$
can you finish?